# node.js fluent-ffmpeg merge 2 images in one image

Tags: node.js, fluent-ffmpeg

I am trying to merge 2 different images in one image. I cannot find anything on the web.

Please send me stuff to put it in the script NOT cmdline

Comment: Does this help https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images ?

Comment: Solved. I used https://github.com/lovell/sharp this works really well

Comment: @1euro7cent can you help me with reference to this, i didnt find any thing about merging images via sharp.